# Change default text shown for ImageField when not empty

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms, django-models

I have following field:

```
photo = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True,upload_to="product_images")
```

I have defined the following layout in `forms.py` for this field:

```
self.fields['photo'].label = "Asset Image"
self.helper.layout = Layout(
    'photo',
    HTML("""{% if form.photo.value %}
               <img height="80"
                    width="160"
                    class="pull-left"
                    src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ form.photo.value }}">
             {% endif %}""", ),
```

Now I can upload images associated with this particular field just fine. However when I try to update the image I see the following in my template:

[image: screenshot of image field]

Is there any way I can change the layout so that only the browse button and existing image are shown when the image field is not empty? In other words, remove the text `Currently: product_images/km_2.jpeg Clear Change:`

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure `ImageField` uses `ClearableFileInput` in order to render the HTML.

So to get rid of the "Currently: ... Clear" stuff you need to subclass the `ClearableFileInput` and modify the `template_with_clear` and/or `template_with_initial` members.

```
from django.forms import ClearableFileInput

class MyClearableFileInput(ClearableFileInput):
     template_with_initial = '%(input_text)s: %(input)s'
```

Subsequently you use `MyClearableFileInput`, e.g.:

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = {
            "file": MyClearableFileInput(),
        }
```

I tested this with a `FileField`, but I'm pretty sure it will also work with an `ImageField`.