# Delete colon after initial_text and input_text django forms

Tags: python, css, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to customize my form design and there are some things I dont know how to delete/ change.

**forms.py**

```py
class UserProfileAvatarForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['avatar']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['avatar'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'file', 'id': 'formFile'})
```

This is what I get:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

How can I get rid of "Currently" and "Change:"?

This is the html output:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I can give `display:none` to **a** tag to make it disappear, but "Currently" and "Change:" dont have a tag. Is there any solution?

It has to do with css or with forms.py?

---

#### Update after AMG helped

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

**forms.py**

```py
class MyClearableFileInput(ClearableFileInput):
    initial_text = ''
    input_text = ''

class UserProfileAvatarForm(forms.ModelForm):

    avatar = forms.ImageField(widget=MyClearableFileInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['avatar']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['avatar'].label_suffix = ''
        self.fields['avatar'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'file', 'id': 'formFile'})
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to override `/django/forms/widgets/ClearableFileInput()` and set initial_text to "".

See [Change default text shown for ImageField when not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25300633/change-default-text-shown-for-imagefield-when-not-empty) for a similar question, but I believe the property used to be `template_with_initial` and it seems to be `initial_text` now.

Do the same for `input_text` in that same Class.

Alternatively, since the widget uses `gettext()` to translate if needed, you could update your message file with the english tran(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations).

**Edit:**

Create your own custom widget without the ":". Use this stock one (https://github.com/django/django/blob/76c0b32f826469320c59709d31e2f2126dd7c505/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/clearable_file_input.html) as your starting point, save it in your app, then use the `template_name` to point to your custom widget template (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/renderers/#overriding-built-in-widget-templates). If you do this you may as well undo the previous override of the `ClearableFileInput()` as it would be unecessary if you remove the `initial_text` from the html template.

Stock `clearable_file_input.html` looks like:

```
{% if widget.is_initial %}{{ widget.initial_text }}: <a href="{{ widget.value.url }}">{{ widget.value }}</a>{% if not widget.required %}
<input type="checkbox" name="{{ widget.checkbox_name }}" id="{{ widget.checkbox_id }}"{% if widget.attrs.disabled %} disabled{% endif %}>
<label for="{{ widget.checkbox_id }}">{{ widget.clear_checkbox_label }}</label>{% endif %}<br>
{{ widget.input_text }}:{% endif %}
<input type="{{ widget.type }}" name="{{ widget.name }}"{% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %}>
```

and you probably want something like:

```
{% if widget.is_initial %}<a href="{{ widget.value.url }}">{{ widget.value }}</a>{% if not widget.required %}
<input type="checkbox" name="{{ widget.checkbox_name }}" id="{{ widget.checkbox_id }}"{% if widget.attrs.disabled %} disabled{% endif %}>
<label for="{{ widget.checkbox_id }}">{{ widget.clear_checkbox_label }}</label>{% endif %}<br>
{% endif %}
<input type="{{ widget.type }}" name="{{ widget.name }}"{% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %}>
```

Comment: I managed to delete `Curently` and` Change` but I was left with `:` after each one. label_sufix help me delete `:` aftaer **Avatar**. Any idea of what i could do about `:`?
I updated the post with some new photos and code to see the changes

Comment: I just realised I can do something else. Instead of loading my form **avatar** with an instance I could just load a clean form and that doesnt give me `curently` and `change`. It's just the file input. But I learnt new things. Ty agian

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my instance which loaded my form with a `clean form`

[image]